# Mock a Angular 1.5 component in unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a basic angular 1.5 component looking like this :

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .component('techs', {
    templateUrl: 'app/techs/techs.html',
    controller: TechsController
  });
```

and I would like to mock **only this component** and not the whole app because `angular.mock.module('app')` mocks every components of the app. Is there a way to do it ?
I tried `angular.mock.module('techs')` but I have this error occuring :

```
Failed to instantiate module techs due to:
Module 'techs' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it
```

Comment: Did you forget to add it to the karma.conf.js file?

Comment: Nope, it is there.

Comment: Do you mean instantiate only that component? Why don't you want to instantiate the whole module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject components by $componentController.

```
Forex: component = $componentController('Component', {yourscope}, {yourbindings});
```

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you, but I found these explanations better:
1) https://medium.com/@defields923/angulars-componentcontroller-c5370d7c16c7
2) https://www.codelord.net/2017/01/09/unit-testing-angular-components-with-%24componentcontroller/

Answer (score -1):

I have found that having at least 1 or 2 layers of nesting in my angular module definitions has helped with testing them. For example, you could do this:

```
angular.module('app.ui')
    .component('techs', {
        templateUrl: 'app/techs/techs.html',
        controller: TechsController
    });
```

This would then allow you to not stress about global namespace pollution and the potential overheard you're worried about.

Although, I realize that doesn't really directly answer your question. Back to your example for a moment:

```
    angular.module('app')
        .component('techs', {
            templateUrl: 'app/techs/techs.html',
            controller: TechsController
         });
```

If you are truly unit testing, then in theory - you would only be loading this file by itself (and not

Comment: Not a complete answer. Literally.